# How do I override the numbering for one specific li in an ordered list

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm transcribing legal documents that come with ordered lists, but there's a catch. Law-makers are lazy and when adding a new clause between clauses 2, and 3, they name it 2A.

As an example, here's some original text:

> 6 High treason
>     (1) Any person who abrogates or subverts or suspends or holds in abeyance, or attempts or conspires to abrogate or subvert or suspend or hold in abeyance, the Constitution by use of force or show of force or by any other unconstitutional means shall be guilty of high treason.
>     (2) Any person aiding or abetting  or collaborating the acts mentioned in clause (1) shall likewise be guilty of high treason.
>     (2A)    An act of high treason mentioned in clause (1) or clause (2) shall not be validated by any court including the Supreme Court and a High Court.
>     (3)  Majlis-e-Shoora (Parliament) shall by law provide for the punishment of persons found guilty of high treason.

When coverted to HTML, it's marked up as:

```
<article>
  <div>
    <div>6&mdash;<em>High treason</em></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ol type="1">
    <li>Any person who abrogates or subverts or suspends or holds in abeyance, or attempts or conspires to abrogate or subvert or suspend or hold in abeyance, the Constitution by use of force or show of force or by any other unconstitutional means shall be guilty of high treason.</li>
    <li>Any person aiding or abetting  or collaborating the acts mentioned in clause (1) shall likewise be guilty of high treason.</li>
    <li>An act of high treason mentioned in clause (1) or clause (2) shall not be validated by any court including the Supreme Court and a High Court.</li>
    <li>Majlis-e-Shoora (Parliament) shall by law provide for the punishment of persons found guilty of high treason.</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</article>
```

It renders (obviously) as:

```
6—High treason
  1. Any person who abrogates or subverts or suspends or holds in abeyance, or attempts or conspires to abrogate or subvert or suspend or hold in abeyance, the Constitution by use of force or show of force or by any other unconstitutional means shall be guilty of high treason.
  2. Any person aiding or abetting or collaborating the acts mentioned in clause (1) shall likewise be guilty of high treason.
  3. An act of high treason mentioned in clause (1) or clause (2) shall not be validated by any court including the Supreme Court and a High Court.
  4. Majlis-e-Shoora (Parliament) shall by law provide for the punishment of persons found guilty of high treason.
```

---

**Question:** How can I override the number on a specific `li` and restart the count from the next onwards?

I.e, how do I change 3rd item in the `ol` to be `2A`, and 4th to be `3`.

Here's a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gilani/53k0ya4b/) to make it easy to get started! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest *not* to use `ol`, nor another list element.

Just because content is numbered, doesn’t mean that `ol` has to be used (nor that it’s necessarily appropriate to use it). Semantically, it could be represented as a numbered sequence of paragraphs. Using `ol` could be warranted if you have a hierarchy (i.e., nested lists), but that doesn’t seem to be the case here.

Even *if* `ol` is semantically appropriate: If you can’t represent the numbering with `start` and `value` (and it seems that you can’t, in your case), the content only makes sense in combination with CSS. But we shouldn’t rely on CSS for conveying the meaning of the content. A user agent without CSS support (or a user agent applying a user-specific style sheet that overwrites the relevant part) would get a different numbering. When making references to these list items, it can lead to misunderstandings, possibly critical ones (especially in the case of legal documents).

So I would go with something like this:

```html
<section>
  <h2>6 High treason</h2>

  <p>(1) Any person who abrogates or subverts or suspends or holds in abeyance, or attempts or conspires to abrogate or subvert or suspend or hold in abeyance, the Constitution by use of force or show of force or by any other unconstitutional means shall be guilty of high treason.</p>
  <p>(2) Any person aiding or abetting or collaborating the acts mentioned in clause (1) shall likewise be guilty of high treason.</p>
  <p>(2A) An act of high treason mentioned in clause (1) or clause (2) shall not be validated by any court including the Supreme Court and a High Court.</p>
  <p>(3) Majlis-e-Shoora (Parliament) shall by law provide for the punishment of persons found guilty of high treason.</p>

</section>
```

This would also allow you to use `a` for the numbers so that specific clauses can be linked:

```html
<section id="6">
  <h2>6 High treason</h2>

  <p id="6-1">
    <a href="#6-1">(1)</a>
    Any person who abrogates or subverts or suspends or holds in abeyance, or attempts or conspires to abrogate or subvert or suspend or hold in abeyance, the Constitution by use of force or show of force or by any other unconstitutional means shall be guilty of high treason.
  </p>

  <p id="6-2">
    <a href="#6-2">(2)</a>
    Any person aiding or abetting or collaborating the acts mentioned in clause <a href="#6-1">(1)</a> shall likewise be guilty of high treason.
  </p>

  <p id="6-2A">
    <a href="#6-2A">(2A)</a>
    An act of high treason mentioned in clause <a href="#6-1">(1)</a> or clause <a href="#6-2">(2)</a> shall not be validated by any court including the Supreme Court and a High Court.
  </p>

  <p id="6-3">
    <a href="#6-3">(3)</a>
    Majlis-e-Shoora (Parliament) shall by law provide for the punishment of persons found guilty of high treason.
  </p>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used CSS counters to control the numbering of your clauses and subclauses. It is a little clunky, but I don't know of any other way to do this.

There are three different counters (big, claus, and sub). I started big at 6 because that is the number you are starting with, but you can change it to whatever you want. Claus and sub just get reset and incremented when the classes of div they expect appear.

```css
body {
 counter-reset: claus;
}
.bignumber {
 counter-reset: big 5;
}
.bignumber::before {
 counter-increment: big;
  content: counter(big) "\2014";
}
.clause {
 counter-reset: sub;
}
.clause::before {
 counter-increment: claus;
 content: "(" counter(claus) ") ";
}
.subclause::before {
 counter-increment: sub;
 content: "(" counter(claus) counter(sub, upper-alpha) ") ";
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="bignumber"><em>High treason</em></div>
  <div class="clause">Any person who abrogates or subverts or suspends or holds in abeyance, or attempts or conspires to abrogate or subvert or suspend or hold in abeyance, the Constitution by use of force or show of force or by any other unconstitutional means shall be guilty of high treason.</div>
  <div class="clause">Any person aiding or abetting  or collaborating the acts mentioned in clause (1) shall likewise be guilty of high treason.</div>
  <div class="subclause">An act of high treason mentioned in clause (1) or clause (2) shall not be validated by any court including the Supreme Court and a High Court.</div>
  <div class="clause">Majlis-e-Shoora (Parliament) shall by law provide for the punishment of persons found guilty of high treason.</div>
  <div class="subclause">Here is a subclause that should be 3A.</div>
  <div class="subclause">Here is a subclause that should be 3B.</div>
  <div class="clause">And now on to 4 and beyond....</div>
</article>
```