# How do I access the value of a data-attribute and use it in a CSS declaration

Tags: css, sass

**Q: How can I access the value of a `data-attribute` and use it inside the declaration?**

Edit: I'm expanding the scope to include Sass.

For example, assume I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="black box">
  <div data-color="green">
    This text should be green
  </div>

  <div data-color="red">
    This text should be red
  </div>

  <div data-color="white">
    This text should be white
  </div>
</div>
```

That renders to this:

[image: Rendered HTML]

using the following CSS:

```
/* Ignore this */
.black.box {
  background-color: black;
}


/* Refactor the three rules below into a single rule */
div[data-color="green"] {
  color: green;
}

div[data-color="red"] {
  color: red;
}

div[data-color="white"] {
  color: white;
}
```

---

How can I refactor the three repetitive CSS rules into something like this pseudocode:

```
div[data-color=VALUE] {
  color: VALUE;
}
```

Here's fiddle to help: https://jsfiddle.net/gilani/54de0zn6/7/

Comment: You can't do it with CSS, you need to use JavaScript. Would you like an explanation of how to do it with JavaScript?

Comment: @JBDouble05 no he don't need JS, he need SASS or LESS

Comment: @JBDouble05, I was afraid of that.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd settle for a Sass way of doing it.

Comment: wait for a SASS guy and you will get it ;) something like this is easily doable with SASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case using inline style is one solution since the values are already added inline:

```css
.black {
  background:black;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="black box">
  <div style="color:green">
    This text should be green
  </div>

  <div style="color:red">
    This text should be red
  </div>

  <div style="color:white">
    This text should be white
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also consider the use of CSS variable for more complex situations (also relying on inline style)

```css
.black {
  background:black;
  font-size:30px;
}

.black > div {
  color:var(--c);
  border:5px solid var(--c);
}
```

```html
<div class="black box">
  <div style="--c:green">
    This text should be green
  </div>

  <div style="--c:red">
    This text should be red
  </div>

  <div style="--c:white">
    This text should be white
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, however, it has to be a `data` attribute because the real reason I'm using this is to change the number on a `li` tag :) I'm definitely going to keep this in mind going forward, though.

Comment: @AminShahGilani you mean what by changing the number of li ? I am pretty sure It can be done without data-attribute ;)

Comment: In normal circumstances, yes, but they're limited to numerics, or single alpha (1,2,3 and a,b,c respectively), but in the docs I'm converting, some lists have items like 1,2, 2A, 3, 4, 5, etc.

It's insane how bad legislature is. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980074/how-do-i-override-the-numbering-for-one-specific-li-in-an-ordered-list

Comment: @AminShahGilani CSS variable can do it https://jsfiddle.net/rw4ga3dz/1/ I don't see how data-attribue will help in this case